# Directed acyclic graph in web UI

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, treemap, directed-acyclic-graphs

I need to display a Directed Acyclic Graph in a web page. I am not looking for an off-the-shelf library or solution. I am looking for suggestions, recommendations or a push in the right direction.

**1. DAG Visualization**

I am not sure of how the nodes and relations will be represented. Viable solutions may be Treemaps, the good old node & line or a combination of that two. I don't have a problem if one node appears more than once on the screen.

I don't need all the nodes to appear on the screen from the start. The user may expand a node by double clicking or zooming for example.

I am open to all suggestions and advices.

**2. Technology**

There are some functionalities that the implementation must have:

- drag & drop
- zoom
- events on mouse interaction with nodes

From my point of view, I have 2 options (Flash is out of the question):

***a. HTML5 Canvas***

Disadvantages: no vectors, basically just an image; no implicit mouse events on nodes;

Advantages: speed; popularity; animations

***b. SVG***

Disadvantages: low speed when there are many nodes;

Advantages: vector graphics; elements are in the DOM so you can have events and so on;

***c. A mix of HTML5 Canvas & SVG***

Comment: Do you need to display an image computed one and posted, or something that computes dynamically?

Comment: I would use SVG, unless you have a very large number of items (like arrows) that don't need event handling on them and for which using SVG slows speed down too much. Note that you can [pan and zoom an HTML5 Canvas](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html) in a vector-like way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to dynamically update your graph, you could probably use python on the server with the [pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/) GraphViz module.

I have not tried this, but it's something worth looking into.